# Unable to run single nightwatch test case

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am unable to run a single, isolated test case in NightwatchJS using the `--tag` switch, whereas if I execute the command `nightwatch`, then whole test suite gets executed.

For example, if I execute the command `nightwatch --tag user`, then all I see is

> Starting selenium server... Started - PID: 4093

But, when I run it using only `nightwatch`, the same script gets executed.

Version details:

- Nightwatch@v0.9.19
- Selenium@v3.8.1
- Chrome@v2.53

Am I missing anything, or is it with version compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your chromedriver version is not accurate. You seem to be using 2.53 whereas the latest version being just 2.45.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I tried to use tags with the repo in the following link and found it to be working. Only difference is I am using NightwatchJS 1.0.18.

https://github.com/spnraju/nightwatchjs-selenium-example